# How to slice a matrix in Eigen by taking n rows/columns and then skipping m rows/columns

Tags: c++, eigen

I would like to ask a question about slicing in an efficient manner in Eigen. I would like to slice the matrix in a way that permits me to take `n` rows then skipping `m` rows and repeating the procedure till the end index. For example, if A is `1000 x 20` matrix, I would like to form the matrix B which is `800 x 20`, which contains the first 4 rows of each sequential 5 rows of A.

I hope that my problem is clear.

Thank you very much,
Saddam

Comment: If you are not bound to use a stable release (e.g. 3.3.x) but can use Eigen master, you can give the new [indexing API](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html) a try.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshapeSlicing.html)

Assuming that you have the libraries on your computer, you could compile the following code. To test how to take one column over three.

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{

MatrixXf M1 = MatrixXf::Random(3,8);
cout << "Column major input:" << endl << M1 << "\n";
cout << M1.outerStride() << endl;
cout << (M1.cols()+2)/3 << endl;
Map<MatrixXf,0,OuterStride<> > M2(M1.data(), M1.rows(), (M1.cols()+2)/3, OuterStride<>(M1.outerStride()*3));
cout << "1 column over 3:" << endl << M2 << "\n";
 
typedef Matrix<float,Dynamic,Dynamic,RowMajor> RowMajorMatrixXf;
RowMajorMatrixXf M3(M1);
cout << "Row major input:" << endl << M3 << "\n";
Map<RowMajorMatrixXf,0,Stride<Dynamic,3> > M4(M3.data(), M3.rows(), (M3.cols()+2)/3,
                                              Stride<Dynamic,3>(M3.outerStride(),3));
cout << "1 column over 3:" << endl << M4 << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this basically i am creating a sub vector from previous vector. I switched columns from 20 to 10 as they don't change.

```
int rows = 1000;
int col = 10;
vector<int>arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
vector<vector<int>>matrix;
    
for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
{
    matrix.push_back(arr);
}
int newrow = (rows / 5) * 4 ;
auto last = matrix.begin() + newrow;

vector<vector<int>>matrix2(matrix.begin(), last);

std::cout << matrix2.size() << "\n";
```